# Jenkins: SVN Checkout missing commit message

Tags: jenkins, svn

We have multiple projects that use SVN for version control.

They have an existing pipeline that worked great, however since a few days we no longer get commit messages, everything else works - checkout, committing - all great, but we cannot see commit messages in the checkout step.

The 'changleog' flag is set to true.

Here is our code for the checkout step:

```
scmVars = checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM',
                      additionalCredentials: [],
                      excludedCommitMessages: '',
                      excludedRegions: '',
                      excludedRevprop: '',
                      excludedUsers: '',
                      changelog: true,
                      filterChangelog: false,
                      ignoreDirPropChanges: false,
                      includedRegions: '',
                      locations: [[cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true,
                                   credentialsId: 'foo',
                                   depthOption: 'infinity',
                                   ignoreExternalsOption: true,
                                   local: '.',
                                   remote: scm.locations[0].remote.substring(0, scm.locations[0].remote.indexOf("@"))]],
                      quietOperation: true,
                      workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateWithCleanUpdater']])
```

The console outputs no error and the pipeline finishes. It's just the missing commit messages....

No changes were made when the error first occurred.
Since then, we have tried upgrading Jenkins and some of the plugins that we use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused be a Azure authentication that ran out:

The changes were received from SVN and stored in a Changelog.xml file for each build.
Whenever the changelog file was parsed, the following error appeared:

```
Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier failed.
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys for app 'foo' are expired. Visit the Azure portal to create new keys for your app:   or consider using certificate credentials for added security:   Trace ID: bar Correlation ID: bla Timestamp: 2024-03-18 14:04:42Z
```

With this error, all it needed was to create a new client secret in the azure app registry and register it in Jenkins.